# ios libpd app doesn't generate sound normally but if i launch with profiler it does

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu, instruments, profile

I have an intense cpu app (synth with 8 voices) based on libpd that doesn't generate any sound, however, if I launch it thru profiler, it generates sound and cpu usage is around 70%

why is this difference? why does profiler allows it to run? is there anything blocking apps that consume more than 50% cpu? can someone explain me this phenomena?

if I take synth voices out and leave only 2 for instance, it works without the profiler.

Any tips regarding would be nice.

Thanks,

With my best regards,

Nuno